# pushwoosh and google cloud messaging difference

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

I am novice in notification sending.

I have read some materials and I encountered with the words like

> pushwoosh

and

> google cloud messaging

For me it(and pushwoosh and GCM) looks like a resource for sending notification.

Also I understand that these words are related but I don't understand this relation(hierarchy)

Please clarify this relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Messaging, or GCM, is a free service by Google that can deliver messages from your server to your Android app. The app can choose to handle such messages by displaying notifications to the user.

PushWoosh is a 3rd party service (one of several, such as UrbanAirship and Parse) that has an API for sending push notifications for multiple platforms, including Android and iOS.

PushWoosh uses Google Cloud Messaging under the hood to send the messages to Android devices.

Your server can interface directly with Google's GCM server or interface with a 3rd party provider,  which can cost you money,  but can be easier to implement.

Comment: I'm adding additional link from Pushwoosh community explaining the difference between GCM/APNS and 3rd party Push Providers:

https://community.pushwoosh.com/questions/834/why-do-i-need-pushwoosh